# Marketing Cloud Journey Builder Split

Tags: journeybuilder

I have a journey that sends email after a decision split. Some of the contacts fail but where can you view a list of contacts failing at the first decision? (not bounced just not meeting criteria) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Update Contact activity to each of the decision split paths and write to a DE the status/criteria that you are looking to capture to understand what is triggering each contact not going down the expected path.

If the entry source is being fed by a SF CRM object you could update via a Campaign Member or Object Activity updating the campaign member status or a field in the contact record.